# Calculate timespan in an List<> of time stamps

Tags: c#, list, timespan

I have a list:

```
List<DateTime> timeStamp;
```

Lets say that the list contains the following DateTimes:

```
2006-09-07 11:46:09
2006-09-07 11:46:19
2006-09-07 11:46:20
2006-09-07 11:46:36

2006-09-07 11:47:49
2006-09-07 11:47:53
2006-09-07 11:48:02
2006-09-07 11:48:15
2006-09-07 11:48:29
2006-09-07 11:48:34

2006-09-07 11:54:29
2006-09-07 11:54:39
2006-09-07 11:54:49
2006-09-07 11:54:59

2006-09-07 11:56:19
2006-09-07 11:56:29
2006-09-07 11:56:39 

2006-09-07 11:58:29
2006-09-07 11:58:34
2006-09-07 11:58:45
2006-09-07 11:58:53

2006-09-07 12:00:29
2006-09-07 12:00:39
2006-09-07 12:00:45
2006-09-07 12:00:54
2006-09-07 12:01:03
```

Now, I want to calculate the total accumulated time.  All of these times are in the same List, and the gaps represent a stop/start section.  I also have no control over the interval of the timestamp.  It could be 10 seconds, it could be 1 minute.  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What is the expected value for the times you listed? Is it 14:54?

Comment: How are the 'gaps' represented in the list? If the only contents of the list are the timestamps themselves, how can a consumer of the list tell which intervals it must not accumulate?

Comment: You've got your sample list divided into sections, which I assume is not in the actual `List<DateTime>`. The groups aren't all even numbers of DateTimes, so I assume we can't take everything as start/stop pairs. Could you go through your list, and say what the expected total is, and how that was generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a new answer if you can define the length of the gap:

```
var length = timestamps
           .Zip(timestamps.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a)      // pairwise entries and timespan
           .Where(gap => gap < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)) // ignore large gaps
           .Sum(x => x.TotalMilliseconds);                // total span in ms
```

This works by zipping the list against itself so that entries that were next to each other are available for selection (ie the list is selected 'pairwise'). Timespans are calculated from these, and large timespans (ie that intervals you want ignored) are filtered out.

Comment: It will be sorted, but that doesn't actually solve the issue.  If you notice the gaps, you'll see that there are 30 second to 6 minutes at a time where nothing is going on.  If I did your solution, that time from would be included, and my calculation would be wrong.

Comment: Sorry what is the definition of a start/stop section? I can't see it other than a 'gap' - how is that represented on the list?

Comment: The problem is that it's not really represented in the list.  All the time stamps are in there together.  I just found out that I will indeed know the interval by the time this comes around.  I'm thinking of iterating through the list, and finding gaps in the stamps greater than the interval, calculate the timespan, and continue iterating to the next gap, and just continue to add to the cumulative time span.  Something like:

`
if element[6] > interval from element[7] then
calculate the time from element[1] to element[6]`

Comment: My new answer shows how you can do it, assuming the gap between sections is definable as (say) 180 seconds.

Comment: I tried to use this:

`var length = timeStamp
  .Zip(timeStamp.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a)
  .Where(gap => gap < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
  .Sum(x => x.Milliseconds);`

And when I step through, length is 0.  The other guy deleted his answer, which I tried and it actually worked.  I'm not quite sure what I missed in this one though.

Comment: Yes, cause the current intervals I'm working with are 10 seconds.  Did I do something silly?

Comment: Yes, somewhat silly since in can see examples of gaps that you want to include that are well over 10 seconds. 60 might be safe. If it still doesn't work I'll test and update shortly.

Comment: @KevinH. Sorry there was a bug in the code, I used `Milliseconds` not `TotalMilliseconds` in the `Sum`. The answer has been updated. You should be safe using a `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` of about 30 to 60.

Comment: While this worked, I decided on iterating through my list, finding the interval, and adding them all up.  Thanks!